# Get Steam API bundle JSON

Tags: json, steam, steam-web-api

Does anyone know a way of getting details of DLC and Bundles from steam?

I can easily get App details with the following URL: (Borderlands 2)
http://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=49520

This is the store page, notice the GET part of the URL is /app/{id}/
http://store.steampowered.com/app/49520/

Now I need to get the same sort of result from the API for a bundle.

This is the store page, notice the GET part of the URL is /sub/{id}/
http://store.steampowered.com/sub/32848/

I tried
http://store.steampowered.com/api/subdetails?subids=32848
and get Access Denied.

Any suggestions?

Comment: And if i need informations about a budle? (Not a Sub) Example: https://store.steampowered.com/bundle/4102/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use package instead of sub to get the information.

You can use below link to access the package info
http://store.steampowered.com/api/packagedetails?packageids=32848

Comment: @Olaia, he didnt provide the link to get more info, the URL IS the answer (not "directions towards the answer" as the link ou referenced in your comment). The URL is the API the user asked, the way to get "sub" info from Steam (as you can click and see).

Comment: Isn't this a package URL not a bundle?

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no way to get bundle info, without scraping the HTML. Only apps/packages.

Comment: Do you know how to scrape bundle pages for other currencies / countries? There is a "steamCountry" param in die Cookie Header but changing this has no effect. Seems that they use IP location check to determine the user country. 

I need the prices for bundles from other countries than US.